# how can I rename as many files as I have in a folder

Tags: bash, macos, shell

I have a folder with 1000 files.

Their name is like below

QET2_ P1_A1 _R2....

QEX2_ P2_C10 _R2....

QEX2_P5_B3_R2....

which only the middle is important as highlighted

and I have a key .txt file in the same folder with this info

```
Sample  P   R   Col
    1   1   A   1
    2   1   A   2
    3   1   A   3
    4   2   A   1
    5   2   A   2
    6   2   C   10
    4   2   A   1
    5   2   A   2
```

I want to check the .txt file and change the name of the file accordingly or save with with a name in another folder. for example

.._P1_A1_..

should be sample1 because when I look at the .txt file , it is

```
Sample  P   R   Col
    1   1   A   1
```

for the ..P2_C10..

should be sample6 because when I look at the .txt file , it is

```
Sample  P   R   Col
   6   2   C   10
```

To change each name manually, I can for example do

```
mv *_P1_A1* sample1
```

I also tried to do it using `awk`

```
awk '-f {print "mv *_P"$2"_"$3$4"* sample"$1}' key.txt
```

But I cannot figure it out ,

Comment: So the only thing that changes is the number after `A`, and it corresponds to the Sample?

Comment: Can you then provide a better sample, please?

Comment: `for f in *; do n=$(echo $f | cut -d_ -f3); new_name="sample$(grep "${n:0:1}\t${n:1}" key.txt | head -n1 | cut -f1)"; mv $f $new_name; done` ? :D (not tested)

Comment: @nik Yeah sorry I forgot a double-quote. It's just a quick and dirty one-line try

Comment: BTW, an ideal [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) has a script someone can run to test their answers (that will always set up input files with exactly-desired contents, for instance; and then an example of exactly what output should be given the input created by that exact script). Indeed, the **V** in MCVE refers to precisely that attribute (verifiability); right now, we're needing to guess whether the environments used by the folks trying to answer differ from the production case, and if so how.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this pure bash script for this:

```
while read -d $'\r' -r c1 c2 c3 c4; do
   f="*_P${c2}_${c3}${c4}_*"
   fname=$(compgen -G "$f") && mv "$fname" "sample$c1"
done < key.txt
```

- `-d $'\r'` in `read` is used to delimit each line on `\r` as per your question.
- `compgen -G` is used for expanding a glob pattern in `bash`.
- Only when `compgen -G` returns a success we perform `mv` of expanded filename.

Comment: it is again converting them to unix executable. Note that I am using Mac

Comment: @nik, ...huh? "converting them to unix executable"? That's not something `mv` is capable of doing, and that's the only external command this code runs.

Comment: @anubhava now, it does not do anything with this version

Comment: @Charles Duffy unfortunately it does, I am using a mac , if you want give me a command line to print the extension of them for you

Comment: @nik, if you use `set -x` to run this code with all commands logged, and perhaps add `: "c1=$c1" "c2=$c2" "c3=$c3" "c4=$c4"` at the top of the loop to make its output all the more verbose/useful, this might be helpful in determining where the behavior doesn't match expectations.

Comment: @nik: I am also on mac and I tested this script there itself before posting. What do you mean by **converting them to unix executable**?

Comment: @nik, ...what do extensions have to do with executable status? I wonder if maybe your files already have `+x` set in the permissions, and when they're renamed to no longer have `.txt` extensions the OS assumes that they must be executables for display purposes -- but that's just display; it doesn't change what they *are*.

Comment: (Do you want your output files to be named things like `sample1.txt`, vs `sample1`? That's easy enough -- to fix it retroactively, `for f in sample*; do [[ $f = *.txt ]] || mv "$f" "$f.txt"; done` -- and consider removing incorrect permissions).

Comment: @Charles Duffy the answer is not giving me any output. I am working on it . however, your command-line is great for f in sample*; do [[ $f = *.txt ]] || mv "$f" "$f.txt"; done and solved my problem already !!!!

Comment: @nik, ...right -- if the files are already renamed away from their original names, because you ran this as-given, then running it again wouldn't do anything right now; adding the command I gave you on top then basically changes the net effect to what it would be if you'd originally run this script with the line `fname=$(compgen -G "$f") && mv "$fname" "sample$c1"` modified to `fname=$(compgen -G "$f") && mv "$fname" "sample$c1.txt"`.

Comment: @Charles Duffy NO, the function above does not convert the files to the name. I used this one as I mentioned above `awk '-f {system "mv *_P"$2"_"$3$4"* sample"$1}' key.txt` and then I used `for f in sample*; do [[ $f = *.txt ]] || mv "$f" "$f.txt"; done` to add .txt to it.

Comment: @nik, ...so you want your awk to end with `sample"$1".txt"`? Why didn't you write that yourself? (Not that generating code with `awk` is a safe or sane approach by any means; if you had malicious or buggy filenames, those could trivially cause arbitrary command execution). Anyhow -- add a MCVE to the question so folks can test their answers; right now, these answers are nothing but guesswork.

Comment: To add `.txt` just use `mv "$fname" "sample$c1.txt"` in above answer.

Answer (score 1):

Relying only on POSIX sh (not bash) features, one can do the following:

```
tr '\r' '\n' <key.txt | while read -r c1 c2 c3 c4 _; do
  : c1="$c1" c2="$c2" c3="$c3" c4="$c4"
  set -- *"_P${c2}_${c3}${c4}"*
  if [ "$#" -eq 1 ] && [ -e "$1" ]; then
    mv -- "$1" "sample${c1}.txt"
  fi
done
```

Comment: your solution seems to be working but does not change the name of `QEX2_P1_A1` one  . also your suggestion to convert `awk '-f {system "mv *_P"$2"_"$3$4"* sample"$1}' key.txt` to `awk '-f {system "mv *_P"$2"_"$3$4"* sample"$1".txt"}' key.txt` does not work

Comment: @nik, I already described how to debug. If you show a list of files that exist at the beginning of runtime and a log of running this script with `bash -x scriptname`, I'll be able to see what's wrong. (If the line containing `QEX2_P1_A1` doesn't have a terminating newline, for instance, that would do it). The `awk` approach is awful and prone to security bugs -- as said before, I don't support it.

Comment: I liked your answer. however, it is very difficult for me to make a reproducible example there. I have one request. I have over 10000 txt files and I want to know how many columns and how many rows they have. Is this possible with bash? for example when I open them with xls file, I can count how many columns they have or row they have

Comment: @@Charles Duffy answer here so that I can also accept and appreciate your help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41048666/how-can-i-know-the-number-of-lines-and-columns-that-many-txt-files-have

Answer (score 0):

I would write a script as following, but keep in mind it's surely not the most performant solution:

```
#!/bin/bash
keys=$(tail -n+2 key.txt | tr '\t' ' ' | tr -s ' ')
for f in QEX*; do
  id=$(echo "$f" | cut -d_ -f3)
  sample=$(echo "$keys" | grep "${id:0:1} ${id:1}" | head -n1)
  sample=${sample%% *}
  new_name="sample$sample"
  echo mv "$f" "$new_name" # remove the echo when you're sure it works
done
```

Comment: Haha ok well I don't have your files and key.txt so you'll have to adapt it maybe... Do you understand the script? For each file, get the interesting part (A1, P17 or Q48 or else), grep LETTER TAB NUMBER in key.txt, keep the first line (because you have duplicates), and then keep the first field (should be the sample number).