# how can I know the number of lines and columns that many txt files have

Tags: bash, macos, terminal

I have many files in my directory. 
It is very difficult to open one by one and see how many lines they have or how many columns they have.

I want to know if there is any automatic way to do it

As an example. I create a txt file in my desktop and call it my file

```
check   myfile  Myname 
FALSE   0      Q9Y383
FALSE   1      Q9Y383
FALSE   2      Q9Y383
FALSE   3      Q15366-2
FALSE   6      Q15366-2
FALSE   7      Q15366-2
```

I paste this in there and so I am sure I have 3 columns and 7 rows (when I open them by xls file)

I tried to do it for one single file like

```
wc -l mytextfile
```

it shows 0

This is only one file, what If I have 1000 files ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given:

```
$ cat /tmp/f.txt
check   myfile  Myname 
FALSE   0      Q9Y383
FALSE   1      Q9Y383
FALSE   2      Q9Y383
FALSE   3      Q15366-2
FALSE   6      Q15366-2
FALSE   7      Q15366-2
```

For a single file, you can use `awk`:

```
$ awk 'NR==1{cols=NF} END{print cols, NR}' /tmp/f.txt
3 7
```

If you have `gawk` you can handle multiple files (`*.ext`) files easily:

```
$ gawk 'BEGIN { printf "%4s%8s\n", "cols", "lines"}
        FNR==1{cols=NF} 
        ENDFILE{cnt++;printf "%3i %10i %-60s\n", cols, FNR, FILENAME} 
        END{ printf "%14i lines in %i files\n", NR, cnt}' /tmp/*.txt
```

Which produces (for me)

```
cols   lines
  3          7 /tmp/f.txt                                                  
  1   20000000 /tmp/test.txt                                               
      20000007 lines in 2 files
```

---

Edit

If you have ancient Mac files (where the [newlines](https://blog.codinghorror.com/the-great-newline-schism/) are not some form of `\n`) you can do:

```
$ awk -v RS='\r' 'NR==1{cols=NF} END{print cols, NR}' your_file
```

Or,

```
 $ gawk -v RS='\r'  'BEGIN { printf "%4s%8s\n", "cols", "lines"}
                 FNR==1 { cols=NF } 
                 ENDFILE { cnt++;printf "%3i %10i %-60s\n", cols, FNR, FILENAME } 
                 END { printf "%14i lines in %i files\n", NR, cnt}' *.files
```

Comment: I did not down vote your answer but I appreciate it . however, it does not give me an answer because I am a mac user and that is why I mention OS X  in my question

Comment: @nik: I am a Mac user too. Both `wc` and `awk` are part of POSIX. OS X is POSIX so it has `awk` installed just like `wc` and other POSIX utilities. `gawk` is a GNU utility and must be installed. It is part of Linux.

Comment: @dawg, ...so, I suspect the OP's problem here is that (from other questions) they're using CR-based newlines in their files.

Comment: @dawg I know that they are part of it but the problem is that it does not work , for example awk 'NR==1{cols=NF} END{print cols, NR}' /tmp/f.txt is giving me this error awk: can't open file /tmp/f.txt
 source line number 1

Comment: replace `/tmp/f.txt` with the name of one file that you have. that was the name of the file on my machine....

Comment: @dawg Admins-MBP:EX2 admin$ gawk 'BEGIN { printf "%4s%8s\n", "cols", "lines"}
>         FNR==1{cols=NF} 
>         ENDFILE{cnt++;printf "%3i %10i %-60s\n", cols, FNR, FILENAME} 
>         END{ printf "%14i lines in %i files\n", NR, cnt}' *.txt
-bash: gawk: command not found

Comment: @dawg this one seems to work but I must run it 10000 times `awk 'NR==1{cols=NF} END{print cols, NR}'`

Comment: @nik, gawk is GNU awk; you can install it with macports or (I assume, since I don't use the latter) Homebrew.

Comment: @dawg  I installed gawk and look none of its answer is right file1.txt should have 4 columns while it shows 16 cols   lines
 16          1 file1.txt                                                   
 10          1 file2.txt                                                   
 56          1 file3.txt                                                   
 20          1 file4.txt                                                   
             4 lines in 4 files

Comment: You need to figure out what the line endings are. If `wc` and `awk` are not counting lines correctly, you need to figure out the format of the file. Try `cat -e your_file` and see if the lines are printed correctly or if you get `^M` where the line ending should be...

Comment: @dawg I get ^M . Also seems your update to solve the problem but one small remark and question and then I accept and like your answer. it counts also the header, but not a big deal. Also you mentioned ancient Mac. but my mac is 2014 and also it is MacOS Sierra , what should I do to update it more because it is the last version

Comment: Your MAC may be current, but the FILES are saved in a format that predates OS X. Where did the files come from? It may be the settings of whatever created the files too.

Comment: @dawg they are saved by windows and then I use it on mac , when i change something and save it again. it seems to work all the function :-D I don't know what the problem might be because to me .txt is .txt , no ?

Comment: @dawg however, thanks for your time. I accepted and liked your answer

Comment: Following the line endings link in my answer to understand why a txt file is not always a txt file. :-)

Answer (score 3):

`wc -l file` will show you number of lines; assuming comma-separated values and no literal commas in the header, `read -r -d $'\r' -a cols <file && echo "${#cols[@]}"` will give you number of columns (in the first line).

All of these will work with wildcards. If you have 1000 files, then, you can run:

```
printf '%s\0' *.txt | xargs -0 wc -l
```

...or...

```
for file in *.txt; do
  read -r -a cols <"$file" && echo "$file ${#cols[@]}"
done
```

---

Note that in at least one other question, you had a text file with CR newlines rather than LF or CRLF newlines. For those, you'll want to use `read -r -d $'\r' -a cols`.

Similarly, if your text file format prevents `wc -l` from working correctly for that same reason, you might need the following much-less-efficient alternative:

```
for file in *.txt; do
  printf '%s\t' "$file"
  tr '\r' '\n' <"$file" | wc -l
done
```

Comment: I'd actually suggest dawg's answer if that's what you want -- it only needs a very minor fix to work with the (non-UNIX) text file format you're using.

Comment: but your last answer is the only answer which really works. none of the others are working

Comment: @ Charles Duffy this one gives me nothin  printf '%s\0' *.txt | xargs -0 wc -l
       0 file1.txt
       0 file2.txt
       0 file3.txt
       0 file4.txt
       0 total

Comment: @ Charles Duffy this one seems to run but does not print anything for file in *.txt; do
  read -r -a cols <"$file" && echo "$file ${#cols[@]}"
done

Comment: @nik, right, because most of them are built for real UNIX text files, and you have the old (pre-UNIX, which is to say, pre-OSX) Apple format. I'm not going to make my answers focus on pre-UNIX Apple-only formats unless you make the need to support such formats part of the question.

Comment: @nik, ...I also *do*, in the body text of the answer, tell how to convert one of the prior answers to work with CR-based text files.

Comment: however, if you tell me what you need to help me, I can try to do

Answer (score 0):

Just use `for` statement.

```
for f in *
do
    wc -l "$f"
done
```

and add things to for loop, when you have any other things to repeat

Comment: If you want to repeat for only `pdf` file, use `*.pdf`

Comment: You mean `wc -l "$f"`. That's inefficient compared to `printf '%s\0' | xargs -0 wc -l`, though: the `for` loop runs `wc -l` once for every file, whereas `xargs` runs as few `wc` instances as possible.

Comment: Also, use the `{}` button in the editor to format multi-line chunks of code, or manually add four-space indents yourself; backticks are for a line or less. Triple-backticks are GitHub-flavored markdown, not available in regular markdown as used by StackExchange.

Comment: why not using `wc -l *` instead of a loop?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre, since we're talking about 1000 files, it could go over ARG_MAX if the names are long.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Thank you for your fix. And you are right. For loop is for handling many files.

Comment: @Junyoung Clare Jang this does not work because wc -l does not work, I dont know why

Answer (score 0):

Your file has ‘mac’ line endings – that is, lines separated by carriage-return rather than newline (which are ‘unix’ line endings), and it appears that `wc` can recognise only the latter.

You have two options: convert your input files to ‘mac’ line endings once, or on the fly.

For example

```
% alias frommac="tr '\r' '\n'"
% frommac <myfile >myfile.unix
% wc -l myfile.unix
```

or

```
% frommac <myfile | wc -l
```

If you have lots of these files, then you could do something like

```
% wc -l *.unix
```

(if you've pre-converted the input files as above), or

```
% for f in *; do frommac <$f | wc -l; done
```

...or something along those lines.

Comment: to be honest, I don't know what I have as input. I just know that they are tab delimated text file. how can i check what you asked ?

Comment: To test if you have pre OS X Mac files, you can do `grep -l -U '\x0D' *.txt` That will print the file name of files that have `\r` in them. Assuming they are text files, they are likely older Mac files

Comment: Or another way of testing the same thing is using `file`.  Typing `file myfile.unix` (the file with ‘unix’ line endings) will produce `ASCII text`, and `file myfile` (with the ‘mac’ line endings) will produce `ASCII text, with CR line terminator`.